# Homesite outline profile editor

Tags: php, ide

I've been using HomeSite since Allaire owned it. I started with plain HTML, then classic asp, now I've been using it for PHP development for quite a while but there's a feature I really want and Homesite only seems to do it sometimes. Most IDEs will show a list of functions on a page. Homesite will sort of doing this with the Tag Inspector feature. If I have a file that is nothing but PHP user-defined functions (ex. `require('functions.php')`) then all the functions show up just fine. However, if my page is mainly an HTML page with PHP functions added in they don't show up in the outline.

I guess I could have all my functions be part of a 'required' file but I was wondering if any homesite jocks might know of a more reliable way of creating an outline profile that would display user-defined functions

Comment: I tried homesite once. It made me bleed. Internally.

I got better.

Comment: Blast from the past!
I loved homesite! - I only stopped using it cos I moved across to linux. Why not try Aptana or eclipse with pdt? I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your question after all this waffle.

Comment: I've tried several other IDEs (the last one was eclipse) but always come crying back. The thing I end up missing most is homesite's 'tag insight' for all the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

I used Homesite myself. Topstyle kinda took over from it (it was by the same guy), and now TS itself has now been sold on, for version 4 - http://www.topstyle4.com/ - (now in beta).

Code insight for the files/classes/functions isn't particularly unique anymore though - I think the various Eclipse based IDEs and the Komodo IDE can also do it now.

Comment: They all seemed to have code insight for the different programming languages but no for html itself. I least not that I've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use homesite, but it sounds like perhaps it could be keying off the file extension. Try saving your file with a different extension, for example: save "yourfile.html" as "yourfile.phtml".